# How to handle and fix Periodic boundary condition (simulation data) by code?

Tags: c++11, visualization, simulation, simulator

Thank you for reading my question.

We use a simulation software to simulate particles  dynamics.
The image below represents the output of the simulation software (for only one particle). The output is a set of points p0(x,y,z), p1(x,y,z),...,p19(x,y,z). we connect the points to get the curve.

[image: Please click to see the image]

The x,y,z coordinate must be always > 0 and < max length.
However, in our case which is called Periodic boundary condition we got some points has a value < 0 (red arrow) and some points has a value > max length (green arrow).

If we add the max length to the x,y,z value ( left Box 1 ) then we will move the points into box 1.
and if we subtract the max length from the x,y,z value in Box 2 then we will move the points into box 1.

Actually, this does not solve the problem.

How to solve this issue, please?

Comment: Thanking people is not relevant to the question. If you must give thanks append them to an otherwise relevant comment. Attach URLs to some text. You could write "This image represents..." and attach the URL to "This image" using the square bracket notation as shown in the help. Please clarify what you want to achieve and where the restrictions come from. I do not understand your attempted solution - it's always box 1. Are you talking about different points when adding and subtracting? Maybe show us both images - one showing the problematic, one the wanted result.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: Thank you valid! I've updated the text by adding the image URL.

Comment: Hi ToniBig, I'vent tried. But I have NO problem with writing the code if I get the idea on how to solve the problem. My issue is only with the logic!